# R count character column

Tags: r

I want to add a column containing the amount of letters a-z in a different column from the same row.

```
dataset$count <-length((gregexpr('[a-z]', as.character(dataset$text))[[1]]))
```

does not work.

The result I would like to acheive:

```
text  |  count
a     |  1
ao    |  2
ao2   |  2
as2e  |  3
as2eA |  3
```

Comment: Can you provide an example, please?  I can interpret this in many ways.

Comment: Sure... basically I want to count each lowercase letter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tricky one:

```
nchar(gsub("[^a-z]","",x))
```

Comment: Nice hack! Certainly better than `gregexpr`.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
numchars<-function(txt){
  #basically your code, but to be applied to 1 item
  tmpres<-gregexpr('[a-z]', as.character(txt))[[1]]
  ifelse(tmpres[1]==-1, 0, length(tmpres))
}
#now apply it to all items:
dataset$count <-sapply(dataset$text, numchars)
```

Another option is more of a two-step approach:

```
charmatches<-gregexpr('[a-z]', as.character(dataset$text))[[1]]
dataset$count<-sapply(charmatches, length)
```

Comment: gregexpr('[a-z]', as.character("AAA"))[[1]] returns 1 as does gregexpr('[a-z]', as.character("AAAa"))[[1]]

Comment: Right. For no matches, apparently gregexpr return a vector with one element, holding -1. I edited accordingly (although @Marek's solution is way cooler)